# How to get words matches with it's count using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, isin

i have 2 Dataframes like

```
set1 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']
set2 = ['a','b','b','c','c','f','h','j','k']

df1 = pd.DataFrame(set1, columns=['name'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(set2, columns=['name'])
```

i want to compare these 2 Dataframes without forloop and get a output like

```
df3 = ['a=1','b=2','c=2','f=1','h=1','j=1']
```

which way i can use for getting this output any examples .??
here i want only the items from `df2` that is presented on `df1`

only print that items only like `df3`
and i need to get the count also ( is that not able on pandas no problem i just need a list like `df3` that is also fine
i used merge func but it's showing inner , outer, left join, right join, these methods so not getting any idea which way is better to do this

Comment: `df1` and `df2` are lists, not dataframes.

Comment: What is that you have tried to get ``df3`` ?

Comment: yes brother i just removed the column name, that's it i will update it

Comment: @Sushanth out_1 = df2[~df2['colume_1'].isin(df1['column_1'].unique())] this one i tried but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps!

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'df1_col':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'df2_col':['a','b','b','c','c','f','h','j','k']})

df2[df2['df2_col'].isin(df1['df1_col'])]['df2_col'].value_counts()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.merge` with `value_counts`:

```
df1.merge(df2, on="name")["name"].value_counts()
```

Output:

```
b    2
c    2
j    1
a    1
h    1
f    1
Name: name, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import groupby from itertools
df1,df2 = "".join(df1),"".join(df2)
for i,j in zip(groupby(df1),groupby(df2)):
print(ilen(list(i)))
```